# Need to pass this code as a command line argument but I'm not sure how. This works in Eclipse but not cmd

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

The code works in Eclipse but not command so I did it wrong. I have to pass this as an argument from command line?

```
public class Unit05_Prog1 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         // Prompt the user to enter a string
         java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
         String s = input.nextLine();

         int count = count(s);
         System.out.println("Number of Lower Case Character is : " +count);
     }

     public static int count(String str)
     {
         int count = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
         {
               if(Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i))) //check for lower case character
                   count++;
         }
         return count;
     }
}
```

Comment: Describe exactly what "working" means, along with "this". Also, you don't seem to be actually using anything from the command line, just console input.

Comment: Your command line arguments are delivered to your program via the `args` parameter. None of your code accesses this variable, so I'm puzzled why you think there's different behaviour between your IDE and the command line.

Comment: Your program works for me from the command line without any modification or any special tricks.  Please explain in more detail what your problem is.   And what do you mean by passing **code** as a command line argument?

Comment: id like to be able to use command line. when i run this in eclipse i can enter a string of letters and it tells me how many are lowercase. it wont work using cmd

Comment: HERE IS WHAT IM TRYING TO DO For this part create a program named Unit05_Prog1.java that will accept one argument from
the command line, which will be a string (you can't get anything else, right?). The program
will then check each character in that string and determine if it is a lowercase character or not
and keep a count. When it hits the end of the String it will print out how many lowercase
characters there are.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get input as an argument just change :

```
public class Unit05_Prog1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     if(args.length > 0){
          int count = count(args[0]);
          System.out.println("Number of Lower Case Character is : " +count);
     }
 }

 public static int count(String str)
 {
     int count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
     {
           if(Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i))) //check for lower case character
               count++;
     }
     return count;
 }
}
```

Comment: this returns nothing when i run it

Comment: For this part create a program named Unit05_Prog1.java that will accept one argument from
the command line, which will be a string (you can't get anything else, right?). The program
will then check each character in that string and determine if it is a lowercase character or not
and keep a count. When it hits the end of the String it will print out how many lowercase
characters there are.

Comment: ok i got it now. i was doing this wrong. i was running the java file and not entering anything after the file name in command line. found a youtube vid that saved me. thanks so much!!!